# IERC20 approval is not setting any value

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I've been trying to make my contract transfer tokens using the IERC20 with the following code:

**Approval Function**:

```
function approveTransfer(uint256 _token, uint256 _ammount) external {
        address token = tokenAddresses[_token];
        token.call(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("approve(address,uint256)", address(this), _ammount)
        );
    }
```

I've already test using just the basic `IERC20(token).approval(address(this), _ammount)` and is not working either. Also I've try approving the `_owner` of the contract instead of the contract address as I read somewhere that it might be possible that because my contract is `Ownable` could cause this but I'm not really sure about this point, anyway it didn't work.

When I try to get the Allowance value with the following function:

```
function getAllowance(uint256 _token) external view returns (uint256) {
        return IERC20(tokenAddresses[_token]).allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
    }
```

Always returns me `0` and I've make sure that the address of the token is working. When I call the `balanceOf` it returns me the exactly balance of the account.

This issue arise from me trying to make transfers, and I've debug it down to this point in the code.

**Note: For those who don't know about this. Is not possible to call the approval to a token in Solidity unless is the same owner of the Token. So you need to approve the transfer using something like Ethers directly from the Token contract**

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `transfer` function:

```
tokenContract.transfer(_to, _amount);
```

Comment: Yes. I wasn't aware that is not possible to do the approval on another contract that wasn't the token contract. Thank you.